# Does division take longer when dividing perfect factors?

Tags: swift, algorithm, debugging, division, bignum

I'm writing a big integer library for Swift, and am running into weird occurrences with testing my division algorithm. It seems to be correct, but when I speed test it, it runs significantly slower when I do division with no remainder than when I try dividing random numbers.

In particular, the tests I'm doing are:

**Perfect Division:**

```
for _ in 1...trials {
    let divisor = UBN.random(bytes: maxBytes)
    let knownQuotient = UBN.random(bytes: maxBytes)
    let product = divisor * knownQuotient

    let (quotient, remainder) = product.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: divisor)

    XCTAssertEqual(knownQuotient, quotient)
    XCTAssertEqual(remainder, 0)
}
```

**Random Division**

```
for _ in 1...trials {
    let dividend = UBN.random(bytes: maxBytes)
    let divisor = UBN.random(bytes: maxBytes)

    let (quotient, remainder) = dividend.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: divisor)

    XCTAssertEqual(divisor * quotient + remainder, dividend)
}
```

And the random division steps end up running way faster. I am aware that in the perfect division tests, `product` is much larger than `divisor`, so it's performing division on larger numbers, but even when I accounted for this, the perfect division still takes way longer.

Is this behavior to be expected? Or is this indicative of some greater error in my division algorithm?

Comment: How are you measuring *just* the speed of the division?  How are you "accounting" for the larger numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test for random division will almost always have a very small quotient (on the order of 0-2), while your perfect division will almost always (minus a negligible fraction) have a quotient of something extremely large.

To think about why the expected quotient will always be small for random numbers, think about a random number between 0 and 100. Half of those numbers are larger than 50, so you have a 1:4 chance that your quotient will be either 0 or 1 depending on which is larger. This is true at any scale. 25% of values being 0 or 1 will dramatically shrink your average. On top of that, 1/2 of all values will have a quotient of 0, since this will happen every time the dividend is smaller than the divisor (this double-counts, so it's not 75% or anything, but it's a lot). The only way to get a large value (i.e. slow to compute) is to pick from the largest dividends and smallest divisors, which is a small selection of all possible choices.

Conversely, the expected quotient for your perfect division is 1/2 * the maximum of UBN, which I presume is enormous.

When you say you accounted for this, you'll need to show some code, because the code above definitely will produce the condition you're describing.

Comment: Ah this makes sense! My "accounting for it" was just having the random tests on twice the size of their integers, but forgot to consider that it's really about the ratio of the sizes. Thank you!